# Cascading <li>-hover effect using CSS

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists

I have got an simple html unordered list.

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>
        Group 1
        <ul>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to use CSS to make a simple effect when the mouse is over an Item or a Group.

```
li:hover
{
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

It works quite fine for "Group 1" or "Item 1" (not contained in a group) - When I'm moving the mouse over the color changes. But if I move over "Item 2" or "Item 3" "Group 1" also remains hightlighted (red background). In this case I only want to highlight "Item 2" or "Item 3".

Has anyone an idea how to do this?

Thanks for your help!

===============================
EDIT

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>
        Group 1
        <ul>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Group 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Mouse Over xxx should highlight yyy
xxx -> yyy
Item1 -> Item1
Group1 -> Group1, Item2, Group2, Item3, Item4
Item2 -> Item2
Group2 -> Group2, Item3, Item4
Item3 -> Item3
Item4 -> Item4

Please see http://image-upload.de/image/r76d79/1c7af56a19.png ,just a quick drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found probably the best solution at the jQuery documentation.
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

```
$('li').mouseover(function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('hover');
});

$('li').mouseout(function()
{
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution isn't a purely HTML/CSS one, but it works. It uses the Javascript library jQuery.
http://jsfiddle.net/XP3Vp/

Put this in the head-section of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('li').mouseover(function()
  {
          if ($('li ul li:hover').length) 
          {
              $('li ul li:hover').css('background','red'); 
          }
          else
          {
               $('li:hover').css('background','red'); 
          }
  });
$('li').mouseout(function()
  {
          $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
  });
</script>
```

Use this if you don't want the underlying list items to be highlighted as well when moving the cursor over `Group 1`: http://jsfiddle.net/CwhhN/

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jquery yet, but I'm working on it. Nice solution. Is it possible to make it able to work with nested groups?

Comment: @youllknow Yes, it does. Wasn't that the whole point? :p

Comment: I'm sorry, but it does not. I just checked both links again. Please read my edit in the question once again. If it's not clear I make a fast pic image to show you what I mean.

Comment: @youllknow I'm sorry, I've been looking for a cleaner way to do it, but it didn't work out. Clumsy, but it works.http://jsfiddle.net/qpBgR/ There **is** a cleaner way to do it but it would involve loading **yet another** javascript library (a jQuery plugiin to be precise).

Comment: Solution works (when removing the else in the third line ;)! Thank you! Can you please provide the Link for the "cleaner way" or the name  of the jquery plugin?

Comment: I've gotten a bit further. This **does** load an additional jQuery plugin. http://jsfiddle.net/DZ4LT/ Problem is that it sill highlights Group 1 when hovering Item 3

Comment: Okay, I get by with your first solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. I haven't got that much experience with jQuery yet, so I've got to experiment quite a lot sometimes to achieve my goal :p
If this answer worked, how about an accept? (Sorry if this sounds intrusive but a lot of people seam to leave their questions with a good answer, but without accepting it)

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is to colorize the `ul` as well ..

```
ul{background-color:#fff;}
li:hover
{
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

something like this http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/DxsDa/ although it will still highlight the `group 1` text..

---

Alternatively you can resort to invalid html but i would not suggest that for obvious reasons.. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/DxsDa/1/

Comment: yes, exactly like the first option you posted (but it will still highlight the group 1 text). Invalid html is no option.

Answer (score 1):

`Group 1` contains `Item 2`. So, when you are hovering `Item 2` you are also hovering `Group 1`.

Thus, with CSS what you want is not possible without mis-formatting HTML on purpose.

With JS you can get there, though.
If this is acceptable, refer to [@RobinJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016791/cascading-li-hover-effect-using-css/8016869#8016869).

Answer (score -1):

Use class or id for UL element (which is parent for highlighted li's) and directly children selector:

```
ul#your_id > li:hover{ background-color: #f00; }
```

It will fix error which happens because you try to highlight every li's elements :)

Comment: This type of thing will become easier with the new subject selectors that were announced for CSS4 :)

`@ul li li:hover { ... }` should then style the ul

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/#subject

Comment: -1: wrong. OP wants item2 to highlight when it is hovered, and your rule breaks that.

Comment: I just gave him a direction! His html is incorrect. It isn't good to use element without wrapper - like a Group. Decision is to improve html, not use some javascript spikes!