# How to hover only the current li in nested ul?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a nested list:

```css
li:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
ul li ul li:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>fnord
    <ul>
      <li>baz</li>
      <li>foo
        <ul>
          <li>baz</li>
          <li>foo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>gnarf
    <ul>
      <li>baz</li>
      <li>foo
        <ul>
          <li>baz</li>
          <li>yolo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Problem is, hovering "foo" will also hover "fnord" and all of its `li` elements. How do I hover only the `li` my mouse is actually hovering over?

The nesting is variable and can, in theory, be endless.

I have setup a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jj8B5/4).

Comment: You want a css only solution?

Comment: @laaposto Preferably so, yet if I have to abuse JavaScript and parent all the the other lis, so be it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A solution for subitems and also for parents is possible without JavaScript, when you will add some inline element, which will trigger hover state.

```css
li>span:hover {
   background-color: lightgray;
   font-weight: bold;    
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><span>fnord</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>baz</span></li>
            <li><span>foo</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>baz</span></li>
                    <li><span>foo</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jj8B5/32/) here.

Comment: This works flawlessly and should be more popular, I had to browse many related questions to find this very elegant solution.

Answer (score 19):

I believe the closest you can get with just CSS is to remove the hover styling from the children of the hovered elements... which doesn't help the parents.

```css
li:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
li:hover {
    font-weight: bold;    
}
li:hover ul {
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>fnord
        <ul>
            <li>baz</li>
            <li>foo
                <ul>
                    <li>baz</li>
                    <li>foo</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>gnarf
        <ul>
            <li>baz</li>
            <li>foo
                <ul>
                    <li>baz</li>
                    <li>foo</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jj8B5/10/)

---

The accepted answer on the duplicate you found is the best way I've seen to do this with JavaScript, using `e.stopPropagation`: [Cascading <li>-hover effect using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016791/cascading-li-hover-effect-using-css). You'll want to be more specific than 'all lis' in that selector though:

```js
$('li').mouseover(function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('currentHover');
});

$('li').mouseout(function()
{
    $(this).removeClass('currentHover');
});
```

```css
.currentHover {
    background-color: red;
}
li.currentHover ul {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
    <li>fnord
        <ul>
            <li>baz</li>
            <li>foo
                <ul>
                    <li>baz</li>
                    <li>foo</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>gnarf
        <ul>
            <li>baz</li>
            <li>foo
                <ul>
                    <li>baz</li>
                    <li>foo</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jj8B5/9/) of the answer from there.

Answer (score 3):

So you just want to directly target an li? Try this:

```
 ul li ul li:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jj8B5/1/)

**Edit**

I also added another [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jj8B5/3/) of where the menu could indeed keep on expanding.

Comment: The nesting can be endless. This will select 'foo', yet 'foo' itself could have a child ul with multiple `li` and so on.

Comment: Exactly, if you click my last example you can see that foo can expand on its own.

Comment: Is this what you meant by endless expanding?

Comment: Ah i see what you're trying to achieve here. The only problem you'll be having is that you dont know how many items each li will contain. So for example if you have 2 items in there you can hover over them and you can pretty much guess where each item is located. If you have 10 or more items, it will be harder to find a specific item. How about this? : http://jsfiddle.net/Jj8B5/5/

Comment: If this solved your problem could you accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use this selector to hover

```
ul ul li:hover {}
```

- it can style only element with foo

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible with plain CSS and no modification to HTML by using `:has()` and `:not()` pseudo-selectors for Chromium-based browsers, but `:has` was only implemented in Firefox 121. For up-to-date support status see https://caniuse.com/css-has

```css
li:not(:has(li:hover)):hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>fnord
    <ul>
      <li>baz</li>
      <li>foo
        <ul>
          <li>baz</li>
          <li>foo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>gnarf
    <ul>
      <li>baz</li>
      <li>foo
        <ul>
          <li>baz</li>
          <li>yolo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Firefox does now support this feature