# HTML and CSS problems with details and background-color

Tags: html, css

How I may can change the background of a hovered item from the list without changing the background of all of its children?

I've tried many ways with ::after ::before :not and many other ways.

It would be great if the answer is flexible so that there could be any number of nested lists.

```css
li:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

li:hover:after {
  background-color: navy;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <details>
        <summary>Hello</summary>
        <ul>
          <li>Hello</li>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <details>
                <summary>Hello</summary>
                <ul>
                  <li>Hello</li>
                  <li>Hello</li>
                </ul>
              </details>
            </li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
          </ul>
          <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>
      </details>
    </li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Your list markup is invalid. A list isn't a valid child of another list. It must be inside a list item.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hover only the current li in nested ul?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990054/how-to-hover-only-the-current-li-in-nested-ul)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only one item, you could set an id.
As example:

```
<li id="list">Hello</li>
<style>
    #list:hover { background-color: navy; }
</style>
```

If you want to change more items, then use this:

```
<li class="list">Hello</li>
<style>
    .list:hover { background-color: navy; }
</style>
```

All items with this class "list" will have the background-color "navy".

Further, maybe this could help you: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.php

Greetings

Philipp